# SpriteKit: Scaling a SKNode not working?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to scale a node (with a SKTexture via UIImage) but I can't get the scaling to apply via this method:

```
    scnNode.scale(to: CGSize(width: scnNode.size.width * 0.9, height: scnNode.size.height * 0.9))
```

or this one:

```
   let img = UIImage(named: "myimg")
   let texture  = SKTexture(image: img!)
   let scnNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
   scnNode.setScale(0.9)
```

This kind of works for some reason (but it doesn't scale by 0.9 the first time this is applied)

```
    let rescale = SKAction.scale(to:  0.9 ) , duration: 0.00001)                    
            scnNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(rescale))                
            return labelNode2
```

- I would like to be able to scale without the fake animation hack.

  (SKAction doesn't seem to scale correctly either, i.e if I try to scale by 0.9 I get more like 0.1 size, and if I apply the scaling action again I get a more accurate scaling after the first time, so 0.9 each time keeps scaling down like I would expect, but the first time is not correct which is why I can't use this hack).
- 0.9 is just an example, I've tried many numbers to scale by (even > 1).

Thanks

Comment: Is the size of the node definitely the same size of the texture? I think I've had these sort of issues when the sizes don't line up.

Comment: You have it repeating forever? That is going to throw things off when your duration is .00001 (1 Frame is .0166 seconds)

Comment: ThrowingSpoon  I updated to clear up the first part (how initialize the image / texture). @Knight0fDragon I don't really want to do it via a SKAction, this is just a hack I am doing to just get scaling to work. I really just want to scale the sknode without an animation).  For some reason I can't get the direct scalling to work though (first part of the code above)

Comment: Well you are going to need to show more code, because scale works correctly.  What you need to do is start a new project and include only the lines of code that gets the bug you are getting.  This is called a Minimal Complete Verifiable example (You will see MCVE mentioned a lot here)  Once you have that, share the code so that we can see where you are going wrong.